# Как из родителя менять стиль для одного из элементов стороннего компонента?

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть библиотека стороннего разработчика, которая отдает компонент Table, состоящий из нескольких элементов.
Высота одного из внутренних элементов, назовем его `<div class='toChange'>` из Table меня не устраивает. Я ее хочу задавать динамически из this.state.height.
Можно ли как-то из родительского компонента MyComponent динамически менять высоту у `<div class='toChange'>`?

```
import { Table } from "someLibrary";

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    const y = this.state.height
    return <div>
      <Table />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно в несколько способов

1. Ребенок должен "ловить" `style` и присваивать их на правильную DOM ветку
2. Ребенок должен "ловить" `className` и где-то должен быть `css`, `sass`, `scss` файл который будет импортироваться со стилями для заданного класса
3. Можно использовать `styled-components` которые хорошо работают с переданным `className` и в конечном результате комбинируют переданный класс с тем который они генерируют

Все три примера есть по ссылки ниже

[Ссылка на пример на codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-monad-f15ie?file=/src/App.js)

**Примечание:** если автор библиотеки не принимает `style` или `className` пропс, то у шансы на изменения стиля элемента у вас очень низки. Чтобы узнать точно вам нужно пойти в исходный код этой компоненты и посмотреть какие пропсы она принимает

**UPDATE**

```js
class MyComponent {
  state = {
    height: 0,
  }

  setHeight = (height) => {
    this.setState({ height }, () => {
      // функция вызовется после обновления состояния

      // ловим DOM ветку где надо изменить стили
      const element = document.querySelector('targetClassName');

      // меняем стили только если она существует в DOM структуре
      if (element) element.style.height = `${height}px`;
    })
  }


  render() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Компонент чужой. Он высоту вычисляет сам где-то в своих внутренностях. Править его не хочу - т.к. усложнит поддержку всего проекта. Моя надежда на то,  что можно как-то из родителя вмешиваться. Пока на ум приходит только в componentDidMount() через  document.getElementsByClassName() искать и менять, но чувствую, что тут куча подводных камней.

Comment: Если компонент чужой и не принимает вещи которые я описал выше, тогда вам нужно на обычном JS найти эту DOM-ветку и задать ей нужные вам стили

Comment: делать это в componentDidMount()  родителя - насколько правильно?

Comment: Если компонент чужой, но находится в кодовой базе к которой у вас есть доступ - добавление поддержки дополнительных `props` нисколько не повлияет на поддержку всего проекта. Если он никогда эти `props` не поддерживал, скорее всего никто их туда и не передавал/передает

Comment: `componentDidMount` подходит если высоту вам нужно поставить единожды когда DOM дерево посажено в документ. Если вам нужно будет задавать и изменять высоту реагируя на какие-то `props` то лучше это сделать в `componentDidUpdate()` при этом проверяя на изменения нужные пропсы

Comment: Если хотите задавать динамически в зависимости от `this.state.height` то нужно это делать в функции которая это состояние изменяет

Comment: @PashkovDV я добавил пример в ответ как может выглядеть функция задающая `height` и как поменять стиль компоненту к которому нету прямого доступа через react. Отметьте вопрос правильным если он помогает решить вашу проблему